# Word cloud font size calculation java

Tags: java, font-size, word-cloud

I want to know how i can dynamically adjust the font size in a word cloud according to its count. and font size should change also according to total count of words as frame size is limited and cloud should be seen within that frame without overlapping.

```
int multi = 20;
if((wordsList.size() >= 500) && (wordsList.size() < 1000) || (singleFreq > 100)){
    multi = 8;
  }
  if((wordsList.size() > 1000)){
    multi = 6;
  }
  //q is index of word and times tells how many times word appeared in whole string
  fontSize = times[q] * multi;
}
```

I want to change value of multi automatically according to the situation of word count and total words to be displayed. It crashes when count of a word is 4 or 5 and total words are 10 to 15. because frame size is fixed.

Comment: what is the error message, when it crashes? what does 'multi' stand for? It's hard to understand your problem. You should give more information. At first sight I would assume that your q is larger that times.size().

Comment: it doesnt give any error message. it only keeps on waiting. and shows nothing. even gui form is not loaded. and multi is a variable for ratio which is multiplied by the count of word occurence in complete string. that occurence, i have calculated in array times[] for each word in my list. q is only an iterator